# Pass data between View Controllers - Storyboards segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work in my project. I did exactly the same as in 1 million tutorials.

I have TableViewController with TableView, and simple ViewController for details.

And in detail ViewController in h file I declared:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *testText;
```

then,in m file under @implementation:

```
@synthesize testText;
```

In TableViewController with list I have:

```
    //declared above: UIViewController *ticketDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *destinationTitle = [[ticketArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] pkey];
    [ticketDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
```

Everything, work great. Title is correct, so there must be connection. But, now I want pass other data… So I did testText property and I want to access from TableViewController, but I can't:/

Error says: Property 'testText' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

The really strange thing is.. during debugging, there is testText (like on the screen below):

[image]

Although when I want to implement it.. it's not found:

[image]

Anyone understands what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
UIViewController *ticketDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

to:

```
TicketDetailViewController *ticketDetailViewController = (TicketDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

so that the compiler knows what type of class you're using (and it can find/complete the appropriate properties).

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the detail view controller as a detail view controller, not as a UIViewController.

```
ViewController *ticketDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Instead of

```
UIViewController *ticketDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Also, you should declare your testText property with copy and not with strong.

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *testText;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //declared above: UIViewController *ticketDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
> ```

You don't want a ViewController of class UIViewController, you want TicketDetailViewController or however you have named the destination ViewController class. In that class I presume you have a property named testText.

The right declaration should be

```
 TicketDetailViewController *ticketDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Secondly you don't need this anymore. The compiler does this automatically.

```
@synthesize testText;
```